# how to add a chartseries to a dbchart during runtime in delphi

Tags: delphi, charts, runtime, teechart

I need to add chartseries during runtime cause I don't know how many chart series I'll have at design time, so I wrote some code to add it. However for some reason it's not working...

Most of my charts require only 1 chartseries, except 1 which requires 2. So I could add an extra form with 2 chartseries on, but that would clash my design for this particular form to be generic in what kind of data it can display. So right now, I have 1 chartseries during design time + 1 extra during runtime. The chartseries added in design mode works perfectly. The one I added during runtime is pretty much an exact copy of the properties of the chart in the form file (.dfm).

Form behind:

```
object frmChartTest: TfrmChartTest
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Test'
  ClientHeight = 299
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnShow = FormShow
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object chtTestChart: TDBChart
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 635
    Height = 299
    Title.Text.Strings = (
      'Title Chart')
    BottomAxis.DateTimeFormat = 'dd/MM/yyyy'
    BottomAxis.Increment = 1.000000000000000000
    BottomAxis.LabelStyle = talValue
    BottomAxis.Title.Caption = 'Title bottom axe'
    LeftAxis.Automatic = False
    LeftAxis.AutomaticMaximum = False
    LeftAxis.AutomaticMinimum = False
    LeftAxis.ExactDateTime = False
    LeftAxis.Maximum = 100.000000000000000000
    LeftAxis.Title.Caption = 'Title Y-ax'
    Legend.Visible = False
    View3D = False
    View3DOptions.Elevation = 344
    Zoom.Pen.Mode = pmNotXor
    Align = alClient
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    Color = clWhite
    TabOrder = 0
    DefaultCanvas = 'TGDIPlusCanvas'
    ColorPaletteIndex = 13
  end
end
```

actual code:

```
unit ChartTest;

interface

uses
  Data.DB, FireDAC.Comp.Client, Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, System.DateUtils,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, VclTee.TeeGDIPlus, VclTee.TeEngine, Vcl.ExtCtrls, VclTee.TeeProcs,
  VclTee.Chart, VclTee.DBChart;

type
  TfrmChartTest = class(TForm)
    chtTestChart: TDBChart;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure CreateField(MemoryDataSet: TFDMemTable; AFieldName: string; AFieldType: TFieldType; ASize: integer);
    procedure AddValues(FieldNameXAxe, FieldNameYAxe: string; LineColor: TColor);
    function GetData(): TFDMemTable;
  end;

var
  frmChartTest: TfrmChartTest;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const
  dateField: string = 'date1';
  intField1: string = 'int1';
  intField2: string = 'int2';

{ TfrmChartTest }

procedure TfrmChartTest.AddValues(FieldNameXAxe, FieldNameYAxe: string;
  LineColor: TColor);
var
  chartSeries: TChartSeries;
begin
  chartSeries := TChartSeries.Create(chtTestChart);
  with chartSeries do begin
    ParentChart := chtTestChart;
    Marks.Style := smsXValue;
    DataSource := GetData();
    SeriesColor := LineColor;
    XLabelsSource := FieldNameXAxe;
    Pen.Color := LineColor;
    Pen.Width := 3;
    XValues.DateTime := True;
    XValues.Name := 'X';
    XValues.Order := loAscending;
    XValues.ValueSource := FieldNameXAxe;
    YValues.Name := 'Y';
    YValues.Order := loNone;
    YValues.ValueSource := FieldNameYAxe;
    DrawBetweenPoints := True;
  end;
  chtTestChart.AddSeries(chartSeries);
  chartSeries.Active := True;
end;

procedure TfrmChartTest.CreateField(MemoryDataSet: TFDMemTable;
  AFieldName: string; AFieldType: TFieldType; ASize: integer);
begin
  with MemoryDataSet.FieldDefs.AddFieldDef do begin
    name := AFieldName;
    DataType := AFieldType;
    if ASize > 0 then begin
      Size := ASize;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmChartTest.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AddValues(dateField, intField1, clRed);
  AddValues(dateField, intField2, clBlue);
  chtTestChart.LeftAxis.Minimum := 45;
  chtTestChart.LeftAxis.Maximum := 175;
end;

function TfrmChartTest.GetData: TFDMemTable;
var
  Data: TFDMemTable;
begin
  Data := TFDMemTable.Create(nil);
  CreateField(Data, dateField, ftDate, 0);
  CreateField(Data, intField1, ftInteger, 0);
  CreateField(Data, intField2, ftInteger, 0);
  Data.CreateDataSet();
  Data.Append();
  Data.FieldByName(dateField).AsDateTime := Yesterday;
  Data.FieldByName(intField1).AsInteger := 50;
  Data.FieldByName(intField2).AsInteger := 130;
  Data.Append();
  Data.FieldByName(dateField).AsDateTime := Today;
  Data.FieldByName(intField1).AsInteger := 70;
  Data.FieldByName(intField2).AsInteger := 150;
  Data.Append();
  Data.FieldByName(dateField).AsDateTime := Tomorrow;
  Data.FieldByName(intField1).AsInteger := 90;
  Data.FieldByName(intField2).AsInteger := 170;
  Exit(Data);
end;

end.
```

No values from the Y-axe are displayed. Values on X-axe are displayed.
No error messages are shown, it's just not working as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only functional problem with your code is that you create an instance of abstract [`TChartSeries`](http://teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/lib/html/TChartSeries.html). You didn't mention what kind of series are you trying to create at run-time. To fix this just pick a specific series like [`TLineSeries`](http://teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/lib/html/TLineSeries.html) or [`TBarSeries`](http://teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/lib/html/TBarSeries.html) and your code should work.

Besides that the way you create series at runtime is a bit awkward. You don't need to call `AddSeries` after you set property `ParentChart` of series. Those two are basically equivalent. The simplest way to create parented series is [described in the documentation](http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/tutorials/UserGuide/html/manu423y.htm#creating_series_at_runtime) and it can be a one-liner (this one creates bar series):

```
chartSeries := chtTestChart.AddSeries(TBarSeries.Create(Self));
{ setup series here }
```

You also don't need to set property `Active` of series to `True`, because it's the default value.

Comment: to answer your question, using TFastLineSeries. And you're right, using that class fixed my problem. I didn't know the class was abstract. Thanks so much.